Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes - How to create a key for use with Fernet?
An example Fernet key
The following code produces an example Fernet key, and reports that the length is 44.
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

generated_key = Fernet.generate_key()
print(f'Example generated key: {generated_key}')
print(f'Length of example key: {len(generated_key)}')

The output is (for example)
Example generated key: b'U4f1fCfXWlz7pQ-7WdZKmCY-VtSAln7R-hhvF6qgYa4='
Length of example key: 44

A quick look at this reference tells us that = is a padding character. There are actually 43 characters, if this = symbol is not included.
U4f1fCfXWlz7pQ-7WdZKmCY-VtSAln7R-hhvF6qgYa4

1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11
U4f1 fCfX Wlz7 pQ-7 WdZK mCY- VtSA ln7R -hhv F6qg Ya4

That is 10 blocks of 4 characters plus 3 characters = 43.
Generating an example Fernet key
I am attempting to generate an example key using the following code:
key = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
print(f'Encryption key is: {key}')

base64_key = base64.b64encode(key.encode('utf-8'))
print(f'Base64 encoded key is: {base64_key}')
print(f'Length of base64 encoded key: {len(base64_key)}')

if len(base64_key) > 43:
    base64_key = base64_key[:43]
    print(f'Truncating key to length {43}: {base64_key}')
    print(f'Length of base64 encoded key is now {len(base64_key)}')
elif len(base64_key) < required_key_length_characters:
    print(f'error: key is too short')
    raise RuntimeError(f'key too short')

fernet_instance = Fernet(base64_key)

However this produces the following output and exception:
Encryption key is: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Base64 encoded key is: b'MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MA=='
Length of base64 encoded key: 56
Truncating key to length 43: b'MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTI'
Length of base64 encoded key is now 43

binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Indeed, manually hacking the padding
base64_key = base64_key + b'='

fixes the problem.
How long should a Fernet key be?
The exception produced by my code says
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes

32 bytes = 256 bits. Each base64 encoded character is 6 bits.
256 / 6 = 42.6666... or 43 if you round up. That matches the length of the key produced by Fernet.generate_key().
Why does it not work if the key is too short?
A 43 character key contains enough bits to have 256 bits of encryption. So why does this not work?
It actually has slightly more than 256 bits of information. 43 * 6 = 258
Why does it not work if the key is exactly the right length?
A 44 character key contains enough bits to have 256 bits of encryption, and it aligns with a 4 byte boundary. But, it still fails and produces the following exception:
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes

So even if the 4 byte boundary is some odd arbitrary requirement (is it a bug, perhaps?) then this should work, especially given that a key of length 43 does not have exactly 256 bits of information. It has 258.
Does not work if key too long
Given the above, this is not surprising.
If you don't truncate the key at all, the same exception is produced.
So what is the right way to generate this key?
The logic of truncating to 43 characters and then adding a padding character on the end to increase the length to 44 seems arbitrary.
Is there a better way to generate this kind of key using a password style input?

To clarify a couple of things:

I am trying to deterministically generate a key across multiple machines from the same passphrase


I don't know anything about this, but my intuition here would be to be strict about the statement "32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes": start with a key of exactly 32 bytes. When you base-64 encode those, you'll get 43 characters, the last of which should always have its last two bits at 0. In the example key you gave, you started with 40 digits, 8 more than the mandated 32.

If I was asking a user to enter a password to generate this key, I might hash it to a 32*8 bit hash (possibly a 64 hex char hash, since many hashes output hex, which you can then convert to 32 bytes), and use that.

This question is similar to: Generating own key with Python Fernet. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also the Fernet specification, sec. Key Format:

Take 32 bytes. Then use the urlsafe base64 encoding method on those 32 bytes. That's all that's going on, it's not meant to be a mystery.

One convenient way to do it is to hash the password using a fixed length hashing algorithm, such as sha256. This is how I have done it:
def get_fernet_key_from_password_string(password: str) -> bytes:
    key = password
    hashed_key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8'))
    hashed_key_digest = hashed_key.digest()
    base64_key = base64.b64encode(hashed_key_digest)
    return base64_key

This can then be used with Fernet.
base64_key = get_fernet_key_from_password(password)
print(f'Base64 encoded key is: {base64_key}')

fernet_instance = Fernet(base64_key)
token = fernet_instance.encrypt(b"some example content to encrypt")
print(token)
print(fernet_instance.decrypt(token))


Fernet.generate_key() does not use a password, but generates a random key, which simply corresponds to base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(32)). If you are looking for a deterministic key derivation from a password, you should make that clearer in your question (preferably already in the title and not just with a short note at the end). By the way, a fast hash like SHA256 is a vulnerability, instead a reliable key derivation (at least PBKDF2) in combination with a random salt should be better used.

@Topaco these are good ideas - but in this case it does not make sense to use a random salt - I am trying to generate a key deterministically. (Two machines should use the same input to generate the same key.)

Random salt means random salt per key. Such a salt protects against rainbow table attacks (in contrast to dictionary attacks). Also, a key derivation function like PBKDF2 intentionally slows down an attacker compared to a fast hash like SHA256. Of course, your password should still be as strong as possible.

@Topaco sure but that's no good if I need to generate two identical keys on different hosts

Well, not trying to convince you, just pointing out the vulnerabilities. In the end, you have to decide what your security requirements are.

You still use a salt in password-based cryptography, you just include the salt in the ciphertext. That way the recipient can re-derive the same key from the password. The salt is not meant to be secret.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk sure - but why would that be more secure than just using a password. I suppose it is harder to guess a salt and a password using a dictionary attack, but to be honest if someone is trying to dictionary attack this thing we are really not in the real world anymore. To give an explanation - it's just a simple file transfer utility. It isn't intended to be used on the open internet. So while I accept these situations could theoretically occur, they won't. Even if they did, the data this thing is "protecting" isn't that important, to be honest.

A random salt eliminates the dictionary/rainbow table attack. But at this point, I'm not even sure what your question is.
